# Thread Lock in Shedlock in Multi instance Environment

Tags: spring, multiple-instances, shedlock

In multi instance environment(instances 4), two scheduler are spawning 4 threads. we need to have lock for these thread with respect to particular instance.

Can you please suggest if shedlock will help here ?